# Editar columna tabla jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<table id="tabla1">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Fruta</th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th>Color</th><!-- necesito editar esta columna-->
    </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="1">
        <td>Manzana</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>roja</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="2">
        <td>Frutilla</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Roja</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="3">
        <td>Pera</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>verde</td>
    </tr>


</tbody>
</table>
```

Esta es mi tabla necesito editar la columna "Color" pero solo los que tengan los id de mi array:

```
var id_tr = [1, 2];
```

Y necesito remplazar por verde.

quedaria algo como esto:

```
<tr id="1">
        <td>Manzana</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>verde</td><!-- remplazo por verde-->
    </tr>

    <tr id="2">
        <td>Frutilla</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>verde</td><!-- remplazo por verde-->
    </tr>
```

Muchas gracias !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recorres todas las filas de tu tabla:

```js
var id_tr = [1,2];
$("#tabla1").find("tbody").find("tr").each(function(){ //Recorres las filas
     if($.inArray(parseInt($(this).attr("id")), id_tr) > -1){ //Validas que el id de la fila en curso esté en tu arreglo
          $(this).find("td:eq(2)").html("verde"); //Si sí está entonces buscas la tercera columna que es la de colores y cambias el texto a "verde"
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla1">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Fruta</th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th>Color</th><!-- necesito editar esta columna-->
    </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="1">
        <td>Manzana</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>roja</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="2">
        <td>Frutilla</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Roja</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="3">
        <td>Pera</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>verde</td>
    </tr>


</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: gracias me sirvió !

Comment: Acabo de agregarle un parseInt al obtener el id del tr para que haga match con la evaluación. Qué bueno que te sirvió. Saludos!